# Simplifying radical expression $\frac{\sqrt{p-4q}}{\sqrt{3q^2+4pq+p^2}}\cdot\frac{\sqrt{p+3q}}{\sqrt{p^2+6pq+8q^2}}\div\frac1{\sqrt{p^2+3pq+2q^2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, fractions

Problem:

> $$\dfrac{\sqrt{p-4q}}{\sqrt{3q^2+4pq+p^2}}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{p+3q}}{\sqrt{p^2+6pq+8q^2}}\div\dfrac1{\sqrt{p^2+3pq+2q^2}}$$

My try:

> $$\dfrac{\sqrt{p-4q}}{\sqrt{3p+q}\sqrt{p+q}}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{p+3q}}{\sqrt{p+4q}\sqrt{p+2q}}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{p+2q}\sqrt{p+q}}1=$$
>   $$\dfrac{\sqrt{p-4q}\,\sqrt{p+3q}}{\sqrt{3p+q}\,\sqrt{p+4q}}=$$
>   $$\dfrac{\sqrt{p^2-pq-12q}}{\sqrt{3p^2+13pq+4q^2}}$$

How do I continue?

Comment: I think that's about the best you can do...

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Apparently the solution is $\frac{\sqrt{p^2-16q^2}}{|p+4q|}$

Comment: Are there mistakes in your typing? Check your maths again.

Comment: I missed a division sign in the original problem

Comment: Also I think $\sqrt{3p^2+4pq+p^2}$ in the first fraction should have $q^2$ and not $p^2$...

Comment: I corrected it; it was the first term that was incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the problem as you've (and I've) corrected it, you failed to mind your $p$s and $q$s. It should have been

$$\frac{\sqrt{p-4q}}{\sqrt{\color{red}{3q+p}}\sqrt{p+q}}\cdot
\frac{\sqrt{p+3q}}{\sqrt{p+4q}\sqrt{p+2q}}\cdot
\frac{\sqrt{p+2q}\sqrt{p+q}}1$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{p-4q}}{\sqrt{p+4q}}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{p-4q}\sqrt{p+4q}}{\sqrt{p+4q}\sqrt{p+4q}}$$
$$=\frac{\sqrt{p^2-16q^2}}{|p+4q|}.$$

Comment: Oh, I tricked my self with the typo it seems... Thanks!

Comment: I have a question though, in the next to last step, why can't the $\sqrt{p+4q}$ in the numerator and denominator cancel out?

Comment: @suomynonA You said the solution given was $\frac{\sqrt{p^2-16q^2}}{|p+4q|}$. I was showing how to get that form.

Comment: So is eliminating that part also correct?

Comment: @suomynonA Yes. Both the solution you were given (involving an absolute value) and $\frac{\sqrt{p-4q}}{\sqrt{p+4q}}$ are equally correct.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel: +1 for the $p$s and $q$s.